# Python parse int from django url parameter

Tags: python, django

I'd like to parse a date from incoming URL parameters in my django application. I came up with:

```
def month_transactions(request, month, year):
    current_month = calculate_current_month(month, year)
    next_month = calculate_next_month(current_month)
    debit_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(is_credit=False,
                                                    due_date__range=(current_month, next_month))
    credit_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(is_credit=True,
                                                     due_date__range=(current_month, next_month))
    return render(request, 'finances/index.html', {
        'debits': debit_transactions,
        'credits': credit_transactions,
    })
def calculate_current_month(month, year):
    current_month = re.match('\d{2}', month)
    current_year = re.match('\d{4}', year)
    return_month = datetime.date(
        int(current_year.group()), int(current_month.group()), 1)
    return return_month
```

Where my URL.conf looks like:

```
url(r'^transactions/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<year>\d{4}/$)', views.month_transactions, name='index',),
```

Since 'month' and 'year' come in to month_transactions as unicode strings (year comes with a trailing /) I kept getting Type exceptions when creating a new date from the raw variables.

Is there a better approach; something built into Python or Django that I missed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're making things much more complicated than they need to be. `month` and `year` are passed as strings, so you can just call `int(month)` and `int(year)` - no need for all that strangeness with the regexes.

Year only comes in with a trailing slash because your close paren is in the wrong place in the urlconf regex - it should be directly after the `}`, as you have for month.

Comment: awesome. I knew it had to be something easy:

Comment: Don't forget to surround in a `try` and `except TypeError` block to catch issues without crashing django